# Get server-side php output through select2 x-editable

Tags: javascript, php, web, jquery-select2, x-editable

I am using select2 v3.5.4 and X-editable v1.5.0

I have an `editable` using `select2` sending data via POST to a PHP script running on server and I am trying to print the server output into the js console. I am attempting this using the `success()` function but all I get in the Chrome console upon selecting values and hitting the confirmation button, is just `undefined`.

The Javascript:

```
$(".sel").editable( {
  source  : [{id: '1', text: 'One'},
             {id: '2', text: 'Two'},
             {id: '3', text: 'Three'}],
  select2 : {multiple: true},
  url     : "animalsDetailsEdit.php",
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success : function(response, newValue) {
              console.log(response);
            },
  error   : function(){
              console.log("Error");
            }
});
```

The serverside PHP:

```
<?php
  echo json_encode("TEST MESSAGE");
?>
```

I have tried multiple combinations of paramaters but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I usually set header of my PHP output, so javascript can read the output easily, and also make error reporting disabled so API becomes perfect for Javascript to read it.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
...
...
...
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo json_encode("TEST MESSAGE");
```

You can also set the character set like 'UTF-8' etc in header. This output is easily readable by javascript...
One more thing I have noticed is that test message is a string not an array I suggest you do it like this...

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$output = array();
$output['status'] = true;
$output['message'] = 'Test Message';
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo json_encode($output);
```

in Javascript you can use the output array to check the status as well as message. or You can make another variable for error where you can also put error message...

```
<?php
$output['status'] = false;
$output['error'] = 'error message';
$output['data'] = array();
```

Comment: I have updated the PHP to reflect the changes you suggested, but the `response` variable of the `success()` function is still undefined and thus throws an `Unexpected token u` when I try to `JSON.parse()` it.

I should add that I can read PHP output just fine when using the simple `$.ajax()` function on a test button and this problem only occurs with the X-editable using Select2. I am thinking of abandoning select2 altogether.

Comment: can you show the output? that can be used to understand the problem

Comment: `echo json_encode("TEST MESSAGE");` which is supposed to send back the "TEST MESSAGE" string encoded in json